# How to join with most recent record?

Tags: sql, performance, sas

I have two tables. Table A contains daily information on transactions on corporate bonds from 2004 to 2012, and table B contains bond rating information on specific dates. I need to join the two tables, so that for each transaction i table A, the most recent rating for that specific bond is appended.

```
Table A: daily_transactions
--------------------------------------------
DATE        |BOND    |PRICE
--------------------------------------------
20110401    |AES     |100
20110402    |AES     |101
20110403    |AES     |102
20110404    |AES     |103
20110401    |BPP     |99
20110402    |BPP     |98


Table B: bond_ratings
--------------------------------------------
DATE        |BOND    |RATING
--------------------------------------------
20110401    |AES     |AAA
20110403    |AES     |BB
20110401    |BPP     |CCC


Table C: joined_data
--------------------------------------------
DATE        |BOND    |PRICE   |RATING
--------------------------------------------
20110401    |AES     |100     |AAA
20110402    |AES     |101     |AAA
20110403    |AES     |102     |BB
20110404    |AES     |103     |BB
20110401    |BPP     |99      |CCC
20110402    |BPP     |98      |CCC
```

I have approx. 1,000,000 records in table A and 14,000 records in table B.

**UPDATE:**

What I have so far is:

```
create table test_merge as
SELECT a.date, b.date, a.bond, a.price, b.rating
FROM   daily_transactions  a
LEFT   JOIN bond_ratings b ON a.bond = b.bond AND b.date <= a.date
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM bond_ratings b1
   WHERE  b1.bond = a.bond
   AND b1.date <= a.date
   AND b1.date >  b.date
   );
```

It seems to work perfectly (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d287f/2), however its runs extremely slow with the amount of data that I have. Takes about 2 hours. Is there any way to optimize this to run faster?

I'm very (very) new to sql, and any help is thus much appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion for what query? It would be great to know what you tried.

Comment: @DanielFriis what is the database?

Comment: @hashbrown. As mentioned I'm new to databases and sql, but the query is being performed in SAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to bring down the runtime to 5 minutes by indexing on the `bond` column.

```
proc sql;
   create index bond
      on work.daily_transactions(bond);
quit;

proc sql;
   create index bond
      on work.bond_ratings(bond);
quit;
```

Comment: Good stuff, didnt think it would help with the sub-query. Creating a composite index on bond as well as date might help it even better.

Comment: Thanks @SashikanthDareddy. Saw your answer just after I found this solution. Thanks for your input and time

Answer (score 1):

For a more SAS based approach (instead of SQL), you can use a SAS format for Table B and probably speed it up more.  A [format in SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473491.htm) is just a lookup table mapping anything between START and END to a LABEL. For example, loading this table as a format:

```
fmtname   |  START       | END         | LABEL
-----------------------------------------------------------
$bondRate |  AES20110401 | AES20110403 | AAA
```

Maps any text string between START and END to LABEL. So `AES20110302` --> AAA.

Here is the full code, using your TABLE B above (assuming DATE is a numeric field, if not use `input(DATE,YYDDMMN8.)` to convert it to a number):

```
PROC SORT DATA = TABLE_B;
    by bond descending date;
run;

/*Use lag function to get the start and end date on one line*/
data bond_ratings_fmt;
    set TABLE_B;
    by bond descending date;

    START_DT = put(date,$8);*Character date like '20110401';
    END_DT = put(lag(date)-1,$8);* 1 less than the prior records end;
    *first.bond is the most recent rating for each bond;
    *setting the END_DT to some future date in this case.;
    if first.bond then END_DT= '20991231';

    START = cats(BOND,START_DT);*Cats concatenates and trims spaces, makes AES20110401;
    END = cats(BOND,END_DT);
    LABEL = Rating;
    fmtName='$bondRate';    
run;
*Load the format, using CNTLIN (Control Table In);
proc format cntlin=bond_ratings_fmt;

*Apply the format;
data TableC_withRating (drop=_:);
    set TableA;
    _DateChar = put(DATE,$8.);
    Rating = put(BOND||_DateChar,$bondRate.);
run;
```

You can get fancier by adding an OTHER case to the format - there are lots of good examples on the web with `cntlin` and `proc format`.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to automate the definition of START and END? So that START is set to the rating date, and END is set to the next rating's rating date?

Comment: Yes - edited to put a bit more code in.   The first steps are very similar to Sashikanth Dareddy's code.

Comment: I definitely recommend an OTHER record (hlo='o').  Every format should have an other record unless you explicitly want other to have the incoming value passed through.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that in your case the sub-query is killing the performance.

The following approach avoids the sub-query to make the join process a little bit more efficient.

```
/*sample data:*/
DATA daily_transactions;
input date bond $ price;
informat date yymmdd8.;
format date yymmddn8.;
infile datalines dsd delimiter = '|';
datalines;
20110401|AES|100
20110402|AES|101
20110403|AES|102
20110404|AES|103
20110401|BPP|99
20110402|BPP|98
;
run;

DATA bond_ratings;
input date bond $ rating $;
informat date yymmdd8.;
format date yymmddn8.;
infile datalines dsd delimiter = '|';
datalines;
20110401|AES |AAA
20110403|AES |BB
20110401|BPP |CCC
;
run;

/*Modify the bond_ratings dataset such that for each record we can specify up till when that rating is valid*/
/*essentially we will have two date fields (from_date, to_date)
from_date   bond    rating  to_date
20110401       AES      AAA     20110402
20110403       AES      BB           .
20110401       BPP      CCC          .
*/

/*since there is no LEAD function in SAS, we sort in decending order by date and apply the LAG function - in effect getting the leading value*/
PROC SORT DATA = bond_ratings OUT = bond_ratings_sorted;
by bond descending date;
run; 
/*capture the to_date by using lag function on the date.*/
data bond_ratings_lookup(rename = (date=from_date));
set bond_ratings_sorted;
by bond descending date;
format to_date yymmddn8.;
lag_date = lag(date);/*note: the reason we keep lag function outside the if-else group below because of the way lag-function works-just look it on google*/
if first.bond and first.date then to_date =.;
else to_date=lag_date-1;/*-1, so that to_date is set to 1 day less the next available bond rating date*/
drop lag_date;
run;
/*this sort is not necessary, but if you want to just verify the output then it is usefull*/
proc sort data = bond_ratings_lookup out = bond_ratings_lookup_sorted;
by bond from_date;
run;

/*final query:*/
proc sql;
create table joined as 
select a.*, b.rating, b.from_date as bond_rating_start_period, b.to_date as bond_rating_end_period
from daily_transactions as a 
left join bond_ratings_lookup_sorted as b
on a.bond = b.bond and
(
b.to_date  ne . and (a.date >=b.from_date and a.date<= b.to_date )
or
b.to_date  = . and (a.date >=b.from_date )
)
order by a.bond, a.date, b.from_date
;
quit;
```